# How to deselect a TreeItem after clicking in a TreeView in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I'm coding in JavaFx and I've created a TreeView to display folders and files like this :

```
fileTreeView = new TreeView<>();
fileTreeView.setPrefWidth(screenWidth / 5);
fileTreeView.setMinWidth(screenWidth / 5);
fileTreeView.setMaxWidth(screenWidth / 5);
```

If the user open a single file, there will only be one file in this TreeView. When clicking on this file, it will open create a Tab and put the content in it and put the Tab in a TabPane. But when the user close the file tab and he wants to open again the file by clicking on it in the TreeView, it don't work because he must click on another file or directory to deselect the previous file, and then click on the file again.

So you understand it, if there is only one file, you cannot open it after closing it.
How can I do it. I've already tried things like
`fileTreeView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();`
or
`fileTreeView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);`
but it's not what I want.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: It sounds like you want to respond to clicks on the `TreeCell`, not changes in selection. Just define a custom `cellFactory` and register the appropriate event handler with the cell. Create and post a [mre] if you can't get it to work.